# Connectivity problem with an app on my Android phone

Tags: htc-desire

What can I do about this message: "Could not complete the action due to poor connectivity"--Says Network Issue? I have downloaded an app called LYFT. Everytime I try to get into this app, that message comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Check using different connectivity type (wifi, lte, etc.). Also Check with whomever wrote the app, could be a server issue or bug in app too.